# Lightning issue: pitch black object

Tags: texturing, lighting

I wanted to create a tent but I noticed that the front appears pitch black when rendering.
I even created an area light to make the front brighter but it's still remaining black.
First picture is viewport rendered in Cycles and the 2nd picture shows the Material Preview mode. I downloaded the dark green tent material on textures.com and didnt change for example the roughness, I used the textures.

Greetings

[image: Rendered in Cycles]
[image: Material Preview]

Comment: it might be Z fighting, which means that you have overlapping faces, what does it give if you select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance?

Comment: does the area point at the tent or away from it? It's hard to see...